# Unable to parse XML using Swift3 Alamofire (4.3.0), EVReflection (4.2.0) - is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: xml, swift3, alamofire

I've downloaded the xml files via Alamofire.download (now I have a copy of the XML when my users are off-line). Next thing is to parse the downloaded XML to a Dictionary.

I am getting the following errors when using [EVReflection/XML](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection/tree/master/Source/XML) :

> WARNING: The class '_TtCC13WINSystemInfo15RepeaterUpdates9WinSystem' is not key value coding-compliant for the key '__name'  There is no
>   support for optional type, array of optionals or enum properties. As a
>   workaround you can implement the function 'setValue forUndefinedKey'
>   for this. See the unit tests for more information
>
> WARNING: The class
>   '_TtCC13WINSystemInfo15RepeaterUpdates17WinSystemRepeater' is not key
>   value coding-compliant for the key 'winSystemRepeater'  There is no
>   support for optional type, array of optionals or enum properties. As a
>   workaround you can implement the function 'setValue forUndefinedKey'
>   for this. See the unit tests for more information

Here is a snippet of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<winSystem>
    <timeStamp> AS OF:02/15/2017 20:17:01</timeStamp>
    <winSystemRepeaters>
        <winSystemRepeater>
            <node>1000</node>
            <repeaterId>1000</repeaterId>
            <grouping>irlp</grouping>
            <callSign>VE7RHS</callSign>
            <serviceArea>Vancouver</serviceArea>
            <serviceState>BC</serviceState>
            <country>Canada</country>
            <locationElevation>Vancouver, BC Canada</locationElevation>
            <latitudeDefault>49.26973</latitudeDefault>
            <longitudeDefault>-123.24992</longitudeDefault>
            <freqOffsetPl>145.2700 -600.0000 100.0</freqOffsetPl>
            <url>http://www.ars.ams.ubc.ca</url>
            <notes>IRLP Status  AS OF:02/15/2017 20:17:01</notes>
        </winSystemRepeater>
        <winSystemRepeater>
            <node>1003</node>
            <repeaterId>1003</repeaterId>
            <grouping>irlp</grouping>
            <callSign>VE7ISC</callSign>
            <serviceArea>Nanaimo</serviceArea>
            <serviceState>BC</serviceState>
            <country>Canada</country>
            <locationElevation>Nanaimo, BC Canada</locationElevation>
            <latitudeDefault>49.22750</latitudeDefault>
            <longitudeDefault>-123.97417</longitudeDefault>
            <freqOffsetPl>146.6400 -600.0000 0.00</freqOffsetPl>
            <url>http://ve7na.ca</url>
            <notes>IRLP Status  AS OF:02/15/2017 20:17:01</notes>
        </winSystemRepeater>
    </winSystemRepeaters>
</winSystem>
```

My EVObject Class definitions:

```
class WinSystem: EVObject {
    var timeStamp: String?
    var winSystemRepeaters: [WinSystemRepeater] = [WinSystemRepeater]()
}

class WinSystemRepeater: EVObject {
    var node: String?
    var repeaterId: NSNumber?
    var grouping: String?
    var callSign: String?
    var serviceArea: String?
    var serviceState: String?
    var country: String?
    var locationElevation: String?
    var latitudeDefault: NSNumber?
    var longitudeDefault: NSNumber?
    var freqOffsetPl: String?
    var url: String?
    var notes: String?
}
```

My function that gets called after notification of a successful download of the XML file:

```
func buildRepeaterDictionary(notification:Notification) -> Void {

    SpeedLog.print("Starting buildRepeaterDictionary")
    SpeedLog.print(notification)
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let urlString  = userInfo["fileUrlString"] as? String else {
            SpeedLog.print("No userInfo found in successful notification")
            return
    }

    // Parse XML
    let xmlUrl = URL(string: urlString)
    do {
        let xmlString = try String(contentsOf: xmlUrl!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let repeaters = WinSystem(xmlString: xmlString)
        SpeedLog.print("Opened file: \(xmlUrl)")
        SpeedLog.print("Repeaters: \(repeaters)")
    }
    catch {
        SpeedLog.print("Unable to open: \(xmlUrl)")
    }
}
```

When I print the xmlString just before the `let repeaters = WinSystem(xmlString: xmlString)` statement. I get:

```
Printing description of xmlString:
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<winSystem>\n <timeStamp> AS OF:02/16/2017 06:00:01</timeStamp>\n <winSystemRepeaters>\n  <winSystemRepeater>\n   <node>1000</node>\n   <repeaterId>1000</repeaterId>\n   <grouping>irlp</grouping>\n   <callSign>VE7RHS</callSign>\n   <serviceArea>Vancouver</serviceArea>\n   <serviceState>BC</serviceState>\n   <country>Canada</country>\n   <locationElevation>Vancouver, BC Canada</locationElevation>\n   <latitudeDefault>49.26973</latitudeDefault>\n   <longitudeDefault>-123.24992</longitudeDefault>\n   <freqOffsetPl>145.2700 -600.0000 100.0</freqOffsetPl>\n   <url>http://www.ars.ams.ubc.ca</url>\n   <notes>IRLP Status  AS OF:02/16/2017 06:00:01</notes>\n  </winSystemRepeater>\n
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [EVReflection](http://github.com/evermer/EVReflection) test AlamofireXmlTests.swift you need a varable with the name __name in your object. The XMLDictionary library will in some cases add that property as a node name.

If you like you can write it to a different property by adding the following code snippet to you object:

```
override internal func propertyMapping() -> [(keyInObject: String?, keyInResource: String?)] {
    return [(keyInObject: "name", keyInResource: "__name")]
}
```

For your other issue your winSystemRepeaters is an object with an winSystemRepeater array in it. So you need an extra object for holding the list. So your object definition will be:

```
class WinSystem: EVObject {
    var timeStamp: String?
    var winSystemRepeaters: WinSystemRepeaters?
}

class WinSystemRepeaters: EVObject {
    var winSystemRepeater: [WinSystemRepeater]?
}

class WinSystemRepeater: EVObject {
    var node: String?
    var repeaterId: NSNumber?
    var grouping: String?
    var callSign: String?
    var serviceArea: String?
    var serviceState: String?
    var country: String?
    var locationElevation: String?
    var latitudeDefault: NSNumber?
    var longitudeDefault: NSNumber?
    var freqOffsetPl: String?
    var url: String?
    var notes: String?
}
```

but... I do remember that there is a workaround for this... So why did that not work in your case... Could you try naming your WinSystem property to winSystemRepeater instead of winSystemRepeaters?

Comment: I am now able to parse the XML after changing the EVObjects as you entered. I still receive the error: `WARNING: The class '_TtCC13WINSystemInfo15RepeaterUpdates9WinSystem' is not key value coding-compliant for the key '__name'
 There is no support for optional type, array of optionals or enum properties.
As a workaround you can implement the function 'setValue forUndefinedKey' for this. See the unit tests for more information
val: 'Optional(winSystem)'` I did add the `val` to the error string. Looks like the value is the root element name.